# Test django post with factory_boy

Tags: django, integration-testing, django-serializer, factory-boy

I just started using [Factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in my test and it's working great.

I'd like to test crud view, so at some point, I need to post data (in json) for create and update action.

I'd like my test content to be something like:

```
a = self.client.post(
    my_url,
    json.dumps(my_factory.stub()),
    content_type="application/json")
assert a.status_code == 403
```

which is not working obviously.
I get `<factory.containers.StubObject object at 0x7ffa34e375d0> is not JSON serializable`
Is there any way to do that? Or I need to fill all the post data myself?
(I'm not testing the form itself or the validation, just the post response.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<User>` is a django model and doesn't know how to represent itself as `JSON`. You need to use a serializer like `ModelSerializer` from `rest-framework` or the [django builtin serializing](http://from%20django.core%20import%20serializers) capabilities:
**tests.py**

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', my_factory.stub(), fields=('id'))

a = self.client.post(
    my_url,data,
    content_type="application/json")
assert a.status_code == 403
```

Please note that any test using the **django test client** would be considered an **integration test** by most.

This does not mean that it is a bad test, I have many tests just like your's, however they are integration tests.

If you would like to make this more of a unit-test try `setup_view` from [here](http://django-downloadview.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html#django_downloadview.test.setup_view).